# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'fname' in 'order clause'

Tags: sql, mysql

[image: This is my table]

I got an error saying : Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'fname' in 'order clause'

Question :
Why am i getting this error when my table has this field name 'fname' and all table mentioned is also correct. Can you give me find the problem here.

Query:

```
select concat(fname,' ','(',substr(breed,1,1),')') as names 
from adoption_dogs
UNION 
select concat('There are a total of',' ',count(breed),' ',breed,'\'s') 
from adoption_dogs 
group by breed 
order by names asc;
```

I tried doing this but my output shows like the one enclosed below.

Desired output[image: desired output:]
but last two before 'There are a total of'.

Comment: Your `SELECT` is a `UNION` and there is no fname in the second part of the `UNION`

Comment: Study [Set Operations with UNION, INTERSECT, and EXCEPT - Set Operations with ORDER BY and LIMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-operations.html#set-operations-order-by-limit). If you want to sort combined rowset after UNION then you must enclose separate subqueries with parenthesis except final ORDER BY.

Comment: Note that according to ANSI/ISO SQL, a UNION with ORDER BY like above sorts the _combined_ result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this first. Order is undefined.
Update1: with comment by @jarlh - `UNION with ORDER BY like above sorts the combined result`. Very useful remark for me.

```
create table adoption_dogs (fName text,breed text);
insert into adoption_dogs values('Butty','German Sheperd');
insert into adoption_dogs values('Max','Golden Retriever');
insert into adoption_dogs values('Unicorn','Lab');
insert into adoption_dogs values('Rusty','Lab');

select '1 names' as section
  ,concat(fname,' ','(',substr(breed,1,1),')') as names 
from adoption_dogs
UNION ALL
select '2 totals' as section
  ,concat('There are a total of',' ',count(breed),' ',breed,'\'s') 
from adoption_dogs 
group by breed 
order by section asc,names;
```

Better, with a defined order. We add calculated column (section) for certain order and enclose union in subquery.
In this case,"Names" section ordered by names and "Total" section ordered by count(breed).
For your task, can change UNION by UNION ALL. Update2:

```
insert into adoption_dogs values('Unicorn','Lab');
insert into adoption_dogs values('Unicorn','Lab');
```

For this rows UNION exclude 1 row from output, and, however, counts them in total.

```
select names from
(
select '1 names' as section
  ,breed
  ,concat(fname,' ','(',substr(breed,1,1),')') as names 
from adoption_dogs
UNION ALL
select '2 totals' as section
  ,breed
  ,concat('There are a total of',' ',count(breed),' ',breed,'\'s') 
from adoption_dogs 
group by breed 
) t
order by section asc,names;
```

Result order is

| names |
| --- |
| Butty (G) |
| Max (G) |
| Rusty (L) |
| Unicorn (L) |
| There are a total of 1 German Sheperd's |
| There are a total of 1 Golden Retriever's |
| There are a total of 2 Lab's |

Or

```
select names from
(
select '1 names' as section
  ,breed
  ,concat(fname,' ','(',substr(breed,1,1),')') as names 
from adoption_dogs
UNION ALL
select '2 totals' as section
  ,breed
  ,concat('There are a total of',' ',count(breed),' ',breed,'\'s') 
from adoption_dogs 
group by breed 
) t
order by breed asc,section,names;
```

There order by breed

| names |
| --- |
| Butty (G) |
| There are a total of 1 German Sheperd's |
| Max (G) |
| There are a total of 1 Golden Retriever's |
| Rusty (L) |
| Unicorn (L) |
| There are a total of 2 Lab's |